# Connection to monitor closed MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, discord, discord.js

I am trying to run my discord bot but I get this error

```
[12/4/2021, 2:06:02 AM] - [INFO] - [ShardManager] Started 1 shards
[12/4/2021, 2:06:28 AM] - [ERROR] - connection <monitor> to IP closed
MongoServerSelectionError: connection <monitor> to IP closed
    at Timeout._onTimeout (d:\Default Download\LenoxBot-master\LenoxBot-master\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\sdam\topology.js:438:30)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Single',
    setName: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    servers: Map(1) {
      'mydblink' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    compatibilityError: null,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    commonWireVersion: null
  }
}
```

I have replaced all sensitive information with placeholders. How do I fix this error?

Comment: Is this mongodb compass or Atlas?

Comment: @Zero yes its atlas, why?

Comment: @Zero I added my IP and the 0.0.0.0 to atlas but still does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @AceKiller250 try not to put your ip because your mongodb need user and password. so its secure.

Comment: @IHZAQSTORM33 What would I do then? I have entered all of that info but still nothing

Comment: @AceKiller250 You don't need to put your ip. Try watch this video. some steps maybe can help you. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4X2qsZudLNY

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by doing this:

1. Go to mongodb. In the left you will see a security tab. Under this
   tab click on "Network Access".
2. Then click add ip address.
3. There you'll see a button saying "Add current ip address".Click that
4. you have to modify your ip address a little (the main part!). At the end of your ip address add "/0". Like, x.x.x.x/0.
5. Then press confirm. That's it!
   Hope it will help you